# AWS Elastic Beanstalk. How do I use the default Elastic Block Storage instance (EBS)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-ebs

I've created a new AWS Elastic Beanstalk, which has automatically created an EC2 instance and attached an EBS (Elastic Block Storage) instance at /dev/xvda.

How do I now use this storage?

e.g. 
I'm using node.js, I've tried saving a file to /dev/xvda/test.txt but the folder does not exist.

I've read things like I need to mount it and format it, but how and where are the instructions. Do I need to do this via SSH (which hasn't been added to the EC2 instance)? Everything else seems to have been setup for me.

Comment: Use the `mount` command to check it out. It should already be mounted as `/`.

Comment: Where do I call that command, from the EC2 command line? Do you think I can save a file as /test.txt?

Comment: It is probably the only disk volume attached to the EC2 instance, unless you picked an EC2 instance type that has an instance store volume also. So by reading or writing to any files on the EC2 instance you are utilizing the EBS volume. The operating systems itself is on the EBS volume. You do not have to do anything special to use this volume. Only if you add more EBS volumes to this instance in the future will you need to format and mount the volume, but that isn't a good idea on Elastic Beanstalk anyway.

Comment: I can see the OS is at /? Ok, so didn't see that coming, the OS is on EBS. So I should just be able to create a folder called something like /storage and the EC2 instance will still auto-scale?

Comment: Looks like that doesn't work "EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/storage'".